# Intellisense popping thousands of errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio 2019, version 16.60 for game development with c++ and just since yesterday, it has suddenly started reporting thousands of errors.

Tried deleting the .suo file in the .vs folder, restarted Visual Studio, restarted the system but no good.
Also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual studio and still no change .

I hope someone can solve this as this is becoming extremely frustrating to find my actual errors in the code amidst all the mess.

Comment: Usually the system is right and you have a syntax error somewhere. Take a look at the first error that is reported.

Comment: Can you share some of the errors you are getting?

Comment: Ignore Intellisense and compile the program, do you get a clean compile?

Comment: Did you miss the including library path of your project? Please check under `Properties`--->`C/C++` and `VC++ Directories`.